# Why does "using namespace" try to instantiate templates in that namespace for MSVC

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I have the following code sample ( MSVC 2015 compiled )

https://godbolt.org/g/kccgtb ( for an executable demo )

```
#include "boost/range/value_type.hpp"

namespace foo { 

    template <typename Range>
    typename boost::range_value<Range>::type
    operator|(Range const& r, int holder)
    {       
    }

}

using namespace foo;


int main(){

}
```

which under msvc generates the following errors

> example.cpp
>
> /opt/compiler-explorer/windows/19.00.24210/include/xlocale(341):
>   warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are
>   not enabled. Specify /EHsc
>
> /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_67_0\boost/range/value_type.hpp(26):
>   error C2039: 'type': is not a member of
>   'boost::range_iterator'
>
> ```
>     with
>
>     [
>
>         T=unsigned __int64
>
>     ]
> ```
>
> /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_67_0\boost/range/value_type.hpp(26):
>   note: see declaration of 'boost::range_iterator'
>
> ```
>     with
>
>     [
>
>         T=unsigned __int64
>
>     ]
> ```
>
> /opt/compiler-explorer/windows/19.00.24210/include/xstring(1659):
>   note: see reference to class template instantiation
>   'boost::range_value' being compiled
>
> /opt/compiler-explorer/windows/19.00.24210/include/xstring(1658):
>   note: while compiling class template member function 'void
>   std::basic_string,std::allocator>::shrink_to_fit(void)'
>
> /opt/compiler-explorer/windows/19.00.24210/include/system_error(661):
>   note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void
>   std::basic_string,std::allocator>::shrink_to_fit(void)'
>   being compiled
>
> /opt/compiler-explorer/windows/19.00.24210/include/stdexcept(21):
>   note: see reference to class template instantiation
>   'std::basic_string,std::allocator>'
>   being compiled
>
> /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_67_0\boost/range/value_type.hpp(26):
>   error C2146: syntax error: missing '>' before identifier 'type'
>
> /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_67_0\boost/iterator/iterator_traits.hpp(23):
>   error C2039: 'value_type': is not a member of
>   'std::iterator_traits'
>
> ```
>     with
>
>     [
>
>         Iterator=int
>
>     ]
> ```
>
> /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_67_0\boost/iterator/iterator_traits.hpp(23):
>   note: see declaration of 'std::iterator_traits'
>
> ```
>     with
>
>     [
>
>         Iterator=int
>
>     ]
> ```
>
> /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_67_0\boost/range/value_type.hpp(27):
>   note: see reference to class template instantiation
>   'boost::iterators::iterator_value' being compiled
>
> /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_67_0\boost/iterator/iterator_traits.hpp(23):
>   error C3646: 'type': unknown override specifier
>
> /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_67_0\boost/iterator/iterator_traits.hpp(23):
>   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>
> Compiler returned: 2

under gcc and clang it compiles.

See https://godbolt.org/g/kccgtb

Comment: AFAIK it is a msvc bug. It generally has problem with generic `operator|` - it tries to match it to internal flags inside stl headers for example (a stumbled upon it once and gave up trying). It is a mess that needs to be worked around

Comment: @bartop msvc compiles the given code snippet fine when standard conformance mode is enabled.

Comment: @VTT This is strange, but for me it does not, especially taking into account that msvc 2015 does not support C++17.EDIT: latest msvc on godbolt seems not to give compile errors. It's clearly compiler bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of approaches is to use SFINAE inside template parameters:

```
template <class Range, class = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_fundamental_v<Range>>>
typename boost::range_value<Range>::type
operator|(
   const Range &r
  , int holder)
{ 
}
```

It is more concise and less foggy than the one with sfinae argument

Answer (score 1):

I have a work around from a work colleauge. It's ugly but seems to work

```
#include "boost/range/value_type.hpp"

namespace foo { 

    template <typename Range>
    typename boost::range_value<Range>::type
    operator|(
       typename std::enable_if<!std::is_fundamental<Range>::value, Range>::type 
          const& r
      , int holder)
    { 
    }
}

using namespace foo;

int main(){}
```

Comment: A little less ugly could be doing sfinae in template arguments or return type

Comment: This is not just ugly, but broken.  The behavior of the `operator|` function has changed, since the template parameter can no longer be deduced, meaning it can no longer be used as an ordinary operator, only with a syntax like `operator|<R>(a,b)`.  So @bartop is correct: the SFINAE logic really should not be in the parameter type.